# Validity of reference for hadith number 531, book 10, volume 1 of Sahih Bukhari?

Tags: source-identification, prayer-timings, sahih-bukhari

I looked at the above Hadith number 531, book 10 and volume 1 of Sahih Bukhari but did not find the same Hadith which is quoted here as (summary) Salat should be offered even if one manages to pray 1 raka'a before sunrise or sunset...Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

The hadith as quoted by Bukhari (courtesy [Sunnah.com](http://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/9/33)):

> حَدَّثَنَا أَبُو نُعَيْمٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا شَيْبَانُ، عَنْ يَحْيَى، عَنْ أَبِي سَلَمَةَ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ **إِذَا أَدْرَكَ أَحَدُكُمْ سَجْدَةً مِنْ صَلاَةِ الْعَصْرِ قَبْلَ أَنْ تَغْرُبَ الشَّمْسُ فَلْيُتِمَّ صَلاَتَهُ، وَإِذَا أَدْرَكَ سَجْدَةً مِنْ صَلاَةِ الصُّبْحِ قَبْلَ أَنْ تَطْلُعَ الشَّمْسُ فَلْيُتِمَّ صَلاَتَهُ** ‏"‏‏.‏
>
> Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "If anyone of you can get one rak'a of the 'Asr prayer before sunset, he should complete his prayer. If any of you can get one rak'a of the Fajr prayer before sunrise, he should complete his prayer."

The "Vol. 1, Book 10, Hadith 531" citation is according to the [numbering scheme used on the USC-MSA site](http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/010-sbt.php#001.010.531), which is still commonly found around the Internet (especially on older posts) but [not particularly encouraged these days](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/2441/22).