# Which hadith said "The earth will vomit up what is in its liver"?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

In 2013, Sheik scholar Hamza Yusuf mentions said hadith in [his Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMY4KLIVKxA) at video time stamp 31:09.  But, the number of the hadith is skipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the hadith being referred to:

> #### تقيء الأرض أفلاذ كبدها، أمثال الأسطوان من الذهب والفضة، فيجيء القاتل فيقول: في هذا قتلت، ويجيء القاطع فيقول: في هذا قطعت رحمي، ويجيء السارق فيقول: في هذا قطعت يدي، ثم يدعونه فلا يأخذون منه شيئا
>
> The earth will vomit out pieces of its liver, like columns of gold and silver. The murderer will come and will say: "It was for this that I killed." The one who severed the ties of kinship will come and say: "It was for this that I severed the ties of kinship." The thief will come and say: "It was for this that my hand was cut off." Then they will leave it and not take anything from it.
>
> <sup>— [Sahih Muslim , كتاب الزكاة](http://sunnah.com/muslim/12/78)</sup>

Comment: thank you brother. is there a chapter and number so I can quickly access, like the Quran which is organized by Sura number:Aya number?

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty Refer to https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/56005 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2392 there is no standard numbering of ahadith, it varies with the compiler or publisher.

Comment: it is Sahih Muslim 1013